# jQuery Tabs Slider Required

Tags: jquery, slider, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm developing a website and need a Tabs slider with tabs links and slider functionality.

When the user click on lower links the content will change and same functionality when the user click on next and previous buttons.

Please see the image for better understanding. Thanks in advance waiting for positive reply back

[image: Tabs Slider Preview]

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following helps you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
// Enable or leave the keys
$('.slider').each(function(){
    if($('li:last',this).width()+$('li:last',this).offset().left-$('li:first',this).offset().left>$('div',this).width()){
        // enable the buttons
        $('button',this).css('display','inline');
        $('button.prev',this).css('visibility','hidden');
    }
});


    $(".slider .next").click(function(){
    //Remove the exist selector
    //Set the width to the widest of either
    var $div =$('div',this.parentNode)
        ,maxoffset = $('li:last',$div).width()+$('li:last',$div).offset().left - $('li:first',$div).offset().left - $div.width()
        ,offset = Math.abs(parseInt( $('ul',$div).css('marginLeft') ))
        ,diff = $div.width();

    if( offset >= maxoffset )
        return;
    else if ( offset + diff >= maxoffset ){
        diff = maxoffset - offset + 20;
        // Hide this
        $(this).css('visibility','hidden');
    }
    // enable the other
    $('.prev', this.parentNode).css('visibility','visible');        

    $("ul", $(this).parent() ).animate({
        marginLeft: "-=" + diff
    },400, 'swing');
});

$(".slider .prev").click(function(){

    var offset = Math.abs(parseInt( $('ul',this.parentNode).css('marginLeft') ));
    var diff = $('div',this.parentNode).width();
    if( offset <= 0 )
        return;
    else if ( offset - diff <= 0 ){
        $(this).css('visibility','hidden');     
        diff = offset;
    }
    $('.next', this.parentNode).css('visibility','visible');

    $("ul",$(this).parent()).animate({
        marginLeft: '+='+diff
    },400, 'swing');
});
});

</script>
<style>
 .slider .next, .slider .prev{
display:none;
background-color:white;
border:0;
font:bold 20px Helvetica;
color:#bbb;
float:left;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
    .slider .next{
float:right;
}
.slider div{
overflow:hidden;
text-align:left;
height:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
    .slider div ul{
    width:3000px;// set to an arbitary high value
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-left:0;
}
    .slider div ul li{
        display:inline;
        padding:10px;
        margin:0;
        background:#eee;
        border:1px solid #ddd;
     }
</style>

<div class='slider'>
<button class='prev'>&lt;</button>
<button class='next'>&gt;</button>
<div>

    <ul>
      <li>Apples</li>
      <li>Pears</li>
      <li>Stairs</li>
      <li>Cares</li>
      <li>Elephants</li>
      <li>Spanish Chickens</li>
      <li>Marlborough House</li>
      <li>Thameside Tavern</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Reference:
http://perplexed.co.uk/1991_jquery_scroll_tabs_like_browser_tabs.htm